# JS - How to run something when a function has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Here is a code that should open and close my site's menu. The menu is divided to divs and each one is timed to enter the screen after the other.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s=0;
            function menuOpen() {
                if (s==0){
                    document.getElementById("menu_icon").src = "x.png";
                    document.getElementById("nav_menu").style.zIndex = "3";
                    $('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        element.classList.remove('loading');
                    }, index * 100);
                });
                s++;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("menu_icon").src = "menu_icon.png";
                    $('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        element.classList.add('loading');
                    }, index * 100);

                });
                    s=0;
                    // how to make this part run after the menu has finished folding? 
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        document.getElementById("nav_menu").style.zIndex = "1";
                    }, 1500);

                }

            }


    </script>
```

The content of the page is at z-index 2. The menu when folded is at 1 and when open at 3.

Is there a way to run the command moving the menu to z-index 1 after the menu has finished folding completely?

Currently what I did was to time the animation (1600ms) and use setTimeout. But this timing will change if I'll add more lines to my menu or if someone is clicking rapidly on the menu icon.

I'm rather new to JS and Jquery so go easy on me (:

Thanks of your help.

Comment: You have two variants: 1) Create an expression that will count time for SetTimeout depending on the amount of menu items 2)Read about async javascript

Comment: If you look at the script you will see I'm doing exactly what you wrote in your first option. But this is causing the problems (as mentioned above) and I'm looking for another way around this.

Comment: I see that you set 1500ms manually, but I suggest to count it, f.e. `timeout = amountMenuItems * timeNeedForMenuItem` and then set counted value, so if you add a menuItem it still will be working and changing the timeNeed... you can setup the speed, but ofc there is one problem if your menu items will need different times.

Comment: one more solution to set special class fot the last element, and if animation last item setTimeout `z-index=1`only for time that need to last item. `if(index == lastIndex)  setTimeout(function(){
                        element.classList.add('loading'); setTimeout(zindexFunc, timeNeedForTheLast);
                    }, index * 100);`

Comment: and one more solution - rewrite your code to use jquery animate, it has param - complete which is a function that called when animation completed http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Hi Nikita,
Thank you for the feedback. I set it to 1500ms because this is the time that took the menu to close.
using jquery animate might be the best solution here. I started to testing it already and I'm sure it can work. It is causing me other problems that I hope I'll be able to pass.

Comment: I did rewrite my code to use jquery animate. The problem I found out with that is that it does not run as smoothly as the css animation. In the jquery animate case if I rapidly press the open/close button the animation gets all mixed up. While with css it stays according to order.

Is there a way to check when all the animation has ended and the run the function that change the z-index?

Comment: You need to display all blocks one by one?

Comment: Or you dislike the way animation go(speed or smoothness for example)?

Comment: Yes I do need to display them one by one. I also assigned the animation to a button that when press it runs the animation and the blocks enter the screen. On the second press it moves them out again. All works fine but if I click it to close in the middle of the open animation 1 or 2 times all gets messed up (the order of the blocks entering the screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and with CSS transitions.

```
var s=0;
                function menuOpen() {
                    if (s==0){
                        document.getElementById("menu_icon").src = "x.png";
                        document.getElementById("nav_menu").style.zIndex = "3";
                        $('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            element.classList.remove('loading');
                        }, index * 100);
                    });
                    s++;

                         $("#last").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
                    document.getElementById("nav_menu").style.zIndex = "3";
                             });

                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("menu_icon").src = "menu_icon.png";
                        $('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            element.classList.add('loading');
                        }, index * 100);

                    });
                        s=0;
                    $("#last").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
                    document.getElementById("nav_menu").style.zIndex = "1";
                   $("#nav_menu").scrollTop(0);

                  });

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the code and link to jsfiddle. Unfortunetly jsfiddle blocks the animate method for unknown reason so I don't debug, but even if it code will not work :))) I hope you will cathch the idea. And also some explanation.

Firstly our items are hidden. There are two functions displayMenu and hideMenu, they are similar, but display - run animations from the top invisible, and hide - start hide items from the bottom visible. To prevent mess I use two flags and two classes, first `openFlag` it is say what animations should be played now. Our hide and display functions are recursive and after they end current animation(hide or show) they check `openFlag`, and play next hide/show or start another chain of hide/show functions. It is the most difficult to understand part) **But important that with it you can click as many times as you want and all would be fine and would be never broken by clicks.**

Two classes we use as animation-chain can change behaviour and we need the way to choose items that alredy visible or hidden, so this why after each animation we set only one of this classes and remove another.

Now there is one problem if all animation are ended when we click button we should start new chain of animations, but if chain has been already started we need just to switch openFlag, and when current animation stops, it will change the behaviour. So this is the reason for `btnFlag` it is 1 if no active chain-animations at this moment.

After the last execution of element of animation-chain it will call callback arg, that you should pass, also at this moment will set `btnFlag` to 0, that means that animation-chain stopped. The `openFlag` as you remember changed at moment og click.

```
function end() {
  console.log("here you can set zIndex");
}

var openFlag = 0; //become 1 after we start open elems 
var btnFlag = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggleMenu').click(function() {
    if (!$('.menuBlocks').hasClass('visible')) {
      if (openFlag == 0) {
        openFlag = 1;
        if (btnFlag) {
          var items = $('.invisibleItem');
          var amount = items.length;
          displayMenu(0, amount, items, end);
        }
      }
    } else {
      openFlag = 0;
      if (btnFlag) {
        var items = $('.visibleItem');
        var amount = items.length;
        hideMenu(amount - 1, items, end);
      }
    }
  });
});

function displayMenu(i, amount, items, callback) {
  if (i < amount && openFlag) {
    items[i].animate({
      "width": "100px"
    }, 1000, function() {
      items[i].removeClass('invisibleItem');
      items[i].addClass('visibleItem');
      displayMenu(i + 1, amount, items);
    });
  } else if (!openFlag) {
              var items = $('.visibleItem');
        var amount = items.length;
        hideMenu(amount - 1, items, makeToggleVisible);
  } else {
    btnFlag = 1; //all aniimations ended
    callback();
  }
}

function hideMenu(i, items, callback) {
  if (i < 0 && openFlag) {
    items[i].animate({
      "width": "0px"
    }, 1000, function() {
      items[i].removeClass('visibleItem');
      items[i].addClass('invisibleItem');
      hideMenu(i - 1, amount, items);
    });
  } else if (!openFlag) {
        var items = $('.invisibleItem');
    var amount = items.length;
    displayMenu(0, amount, items, makeToggleVisible);
  } else {
    btnFlag = 1; //all animations are ended
    callback();
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ShinShil/nrtyshv5/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately the code does not work and it is too complicated for me to find out what is wrong as it is way up my level (:

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it.
I moved everything to jquery. Used animate and promise.
This is what came out at the end. It is a side menu that will open it's li elements one-by-one.

```
        var s=0;
        var navMenu = document.getElementById("nav_menu");
        var navBtn = document.getElementById("btn");

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                if (s==0) {
                navMenu.style.zIndex = "4";

                navBtn.classList.add('close');

                $('ul').each(function() {
                    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                    $(this).delay(i * 100).animate({left:0});
                    });
                });
                    $( "li" ).promise().done(function() {
                    navMenu.style.zIndex = "4";
                    });
                    s++;
                    } 

                else {
                navBtn.classList.remove('close');
                $('ul').each(function() {
                    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                    $(this).delay(i * 100).animate({left:"100%"});
                    });

                });
                    s=0;

                    $( "li" ).promise().done(function() {
                    navMenu.style.zIndex = "1";
                    });

                    } 

                 });
             });
```